# check changes on props of type object or array of objects (React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In some cases, we may face using object or array of objects on component props. To check changes on those props, I used JSON.stringify on useEffect deps. And it works. May it be useful than using some hooks to check deep change?

Here is an example on a object:

```js
const obj = {foo: 'bar'}
const [state, setState] = useState(obj)

useEffect(() => {
    setState(obj)
},[JSON.stringify(obj)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `JSON.stringify` to ensure that the useEffect runs since this is an expensive operation to be done on each render. All you need to do is to ensure that you are changing the object reference i.e cloning and updating the object.

Now since the reference checks fails the useEffect knows that dependency value has changed and it triggeres the callback.

However you must make sure that in such case you aren't defining objects or arrays within the function because then reference keeps changing on each render.

A**lso you must note that `JSON.stringify` doesn't stringy functions or class instances or Date instances**

Answer (score 2):

This will work in some cases, but you need to be careful:

1. For large objects this can become expensive
2. This won't work if your object contains non-JSON-serializable objects, e.g. functions.

For example:

```js
const obj = {
   foo: () => {}
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("obj changed!")
},[JSON.stringify(obj)])
```

If `obj.foo` changes, your effect won't run.